# Yii - Behavior not working properly

Tags: php, yii

I'm trying to use the behavior `ejsonbehavior`, but It's not being launched properly.

Ext: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ejsonbehavior/

---

ejsonbehavior Behavior Path:

```
extensions/behaviors/EJsonBehavior.php
```

Model - Users.php:

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return array(
        'EJsonBehavior' => array('class' => 'ext.behaviors.EJsonBehavior'),
    );
}
```

Controller.php:

```
$model = Users::model()->findAll();
echo $model->toJSON();
```

Error Result:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toJSON() on a non-object in .../Controller.php on line x
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the behavior. Your controller function is returning an array:

```
Users::model()->findAll();
```

The behavior is attached to every element of the array. So eather you perform toJSON() on every model in the array:

```
foreach($model as $item) {
  echo $item->toJSON();
}
```

Or you check the docs for a more appropriate method to obtain just one model in order to perform your echo:  http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord